# How to store automation results in to database?

Tags: automation

Could someone point me some tutorial or blog to direct/store my automation results to database for future referring point?

Regards,
Shiva Oleti

Answer (score 1):

There are at least couple of ways to achieve:

> direct/store my automation results to database for future referring

Maybe the most straightforward one is to utilize Test Case Management platform with well defined API. For example, my team had used - TestRail. Most of them, do provide  saving and (simple) analysis of test results for alerting, building custom dashboards, and other analytical purposes.

The other option, we had implemented is building our own persistent storage layer for the above mentioned reasons. But, then you have to build and/or integrate a lot of stuff in order to achieve those. Picking up the best suited [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) is critical. Here is a good blog post, that I found useful for [Storing API Test Results to a Database](https://blog.runscope.com/posts/storing-api-test-results-database-eventn-runscope). Even if it is aimed at specific tool, it gives great guidance and tips, like

> It is best practice to create a dedicated DB user for such usage with restricted permissions e.g. just INSERT. Setting a restricted access port is also advised.